# Autohotkey's text expansion not working in gVim

Tags: autohotkey, gvim

All other hotkeys are working, but a simple expansion like the following are not working.

```
:*:po::p{^}o
:oc:win::Windows
```

They work fine on terminals and other applications, just not in gVim. I searched for a solution on the web and nobody complains about this problem. What might be the problem?

I am using gVim 7.3 1-761 MS-Windows OLE support. If I use a proprietary text expansion software (e.g. Breevy), the expansion works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now see that I needed a space before the trigger word. Adding `?` as the option fixed the problem for me.

:oc?:win::Windows